# Флуд от ботов в комментариях и прочих формах

Tags: бот, javascript

Интересует вопрос. Боты которые автоматически заполняют все поля, отключают ли перед отправкой js?
Если да, то можно просто создать скрытое, поле и если бот заполнит его, то после проверки, понимаем , что сообщение не от человека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чаще всего так. На одном моем сайте этот способ отсеивает вообще 100% спама.
Только поле надо закрывать не JS, а CSS, причем желательно не очень явно:

```
<input type="hidden" name="antibot" class="hidden_for_bot" /><!--плохо-->
```

очень плохой пример.
Лучше:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" class="nickname" /><!--ХОРОШО-->
```

P.s. многие браузеры предлагают автозаполнение формы. Они такие поля БУДУТ заполнять.
Так что обрабатывать эту инфу придется.

Comment: <input name = "nickname" type="hidden" /> Такой прокатит?

Comment: я думаю @knes имел ввиду, что лучше не type='hidden', а style='display:none;', а может лучше вообще style='opacity:0;'

Comment: Прокатит второй мой вариант.
То есть чтобы узнать спрятано ли поле, роботу придется прошерстить весь CSS, что не очень просто.

Style="" писать не стоит. См чуть выше почему.

Comment: А если робот отключит css?

Comment: Ну и пусть отключит. У вас же поле ПРЯЧЕТСЯ CSSом. Пользователям пофиг, а бот только "яснее увидит поле".

Потому-то я и предлагаю CSS: поле прячется только для тех, у кого этот CSS есть. Т.е. все нормальные юзеры.

Comment: Ой, т.е. я хотел сказать, если бот не будет отключать css и заполнить только видимые поля? Или такого не будет?

Comment: Не будет. Прячутся они только визуально. То есть чтобы определить, что его не видно, бот должен будет провести парсинг CSS. А это весьма непросто.

Answer (score 3):

Один с чудесных способов, о котором я недавно читал - это в полях формы запоминать время генерации формы (конечно, зашифровав его немного). А по факту получения комментария - сравнивать текущее время и время отправки формы. Большинство адекватных пользователей вряд ли сможет отправить форму за 1-2 секунды. А вот боты - легко.

Конечно, нужно понимать, что есть и пользователи, которые за одну секунду отправят ответ, поэтому нужно закладываться на размер текста (больше текст - больше время).

Естественно, этот метод лучше применять в комбинации с другими методами.

Но хитрые вырвиглаз капчи - это для ботов:)

Comment: 1) Поставить замедлитель на бота несложно.
2) Заполнить за 1с при помощи автозаполнения - легко.

100% согласен с предпоследним предложением

Comment: Как же бесят эти ваши капчи. Порой чувствую себя ботом =\

Comment: @knes

1) в большинстве случаев этого как раз не делаеют (если только не специальный бот для сайта. Но в этом случае бессильные любые защиты).

2) А как часто используете автозаполнение в ответах на форуме? Поэтому нужно смотреть, если это просто анкетные данные - это одно, а если это ответ в теме - это другое. Но если честно, то можно сделать проще - те, кто слишком быстро заполнили - оправлять на премодерацию. Но это сильно зависит от форума.

Для того, что бы определиться, какое время оптимальное, нужно сначала не ставить защиту, а просто пустить всех, параллельно делая замеры.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас боты распознают скрытые поля и не ведутся на них.
По крайней мере, ни на одном ресурсе где это внедряли, результат не понравился.
Нужно действовать комплексно.

Например мы делали так. Мы в спам отправляли все комментарии написанные не на русском. Скрытый инпут который нельзя отмечать. И вместе с этим проверку по базе данных спаммеров. Поток спама на подконтрольном ресурсе почти иссяк. При этом никаких каптч. Это все уже пережиток ишь мешающий обычным посетителям, роботы читают в лет.